# How to add a new insert row in PFQueryTableView edit mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm wondering how to add a new insert row in `PFQueryTableView`. My table view is working well that loads all PFObjects properly. However, I want to add a new row at the table view bottom so that when I click on that, it will pop up another view controller to create a new `PFObject`. As `PFQueryTableViewController` comes with its `Edit Button` which is only allowed to delete PFObject. Can you help me out?

In *-viewDidLoad*

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

In *-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:*

```
return self.tableView.isEditing ? self.objects.count + 1 : self.objects.count;
```

In *-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:object:*

```
BOOL isInsertCell = (indexPath.row == self.objects.count && tableView.isEditing);
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
}
// Configure the cell
UILabel *cellLocationLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
cellLocationLabel.text = isInsertCell ? @"Add a new location" : [object objectForKey:@"address"];
return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with doing it the way you described is that there is no corresponding `PFObject` to pass into the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:object:` method. This could potentially cause problems. In addition, the user has to scroll to the bottom to access the add button.

A better way to do this (and the way that I do it, since my application does this exact thing) would be to simply add another button to the navigation bar.

In `viewDidLoad` or your custom `init` method:

```
// Make a new "+" button
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addButtonPressed)];
NSArray *barButtons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.editButtonItem,addButton,nil];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = barButtons;
```

Then in the `addButtonPressed` method:

```
// The user pressed the add button
MyCustomController *controller = [[MyCustomController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
// Replace this with your view controller that handles PFObject creation
```

If you only want the user to be able to create a new object while in editing mode, move the logic into the `setEditing:animated:` method:

```
- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    if(editing)
    {
        UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addButtonPressed)];
        // self.editButtonItem turns into a "Done" button automatically, so keep it there
        NSArray *barButtons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.editButtonItem,addButton,nil];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = barButtons;
    }
    else
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

Hope that helps! This is the way I do it (sort of) and in my opinion is a bit cleaner than having a button inside of a cell at the bottom of the tableView.